# Insert data on array text input on edittext

Tags: android, performance

Hi i am trying to insert data on array , i request the user insert data on edittext and have a button insert then other edittext get the number of times user want insert data and the array,
will make trail and the other edittext will go asking for data to user. Thats is what i have.

I can do that on java but i can´t do it on android.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.moda);

    findViewById(R.id.num1);
    findViewById(R.id.num2);
    findViewById(R.id.tvresultado);

    /*Scanner numero = new Scanner(System.in);
    int valor;

    System.out.print("introduzca un valor");
    valor = numero.nextInt();*/

}

public void ingresar(){

    EditText num1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num1);
    EditText num2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num2);
    TextView total = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvresultado);
    if(num1.length() <= 0 || num2.length() <=0){
        Toast toast =
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Introduce un valor", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }else{

        int dbnum1 = Integer.parseInt(num1.getText().toString());//toma el numero de datos a ingresar
        int dbnum2 = Integer.parseInt(num2.getText().toString());
        int vector[]={dbnum1};
        int i;
        //boolean sw;
        //DataInputStream oCadena;

        vector=new int[dbnum1];
        //oCadena = new DataInputStream(System.in);

        //System.out.println("Ingrese el numero de datos");

        for(dbnum2=0;dbnum2<=vector.length;dbnum2++){
            System.out.println(""+vector[dbnum2]);
        }


    }
```

}

```
}
```

Comment: Where exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish, but I gather that you are having difficulty finding an equivalent to Java's `System.in` and `System.out`. You need to replace this text-based interaction with buttons and text fields on the screen. There's a simple way to connect buttons (or any view, actually) with code in your `Activity` class. This is to set an `android:onClick` attribute (which automatically makes the view clickable). For instance, your layout (`res/layout/moda.xml`) might have a button:

```
<Button
    android:text="@string/ingrese"
    android:onClick="ingresar"
    . . . />
```

The name you give to the `android:onClick` attribute can be any string that is a legal Java method name. In your activity, you would define the corresponding method:

```
public void ingresar(View view) {
    // read and process the data in the text fields
}
```

Note that although the name of the method (which must match the name of the `android:onClick` attribute) can be anything you choose, the method must be of type `public void` and have a single `View` argument.

After that, it's just a matter of getting the logic right for what you are trying to do.

**EDIT**

Per request, here's some sample code that might do what you want:

*res/layout/moda.xml*:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/num1"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/num2"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/resultado"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/ingrese"
            android:onClick="ingresar"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

in *MyActivity.java*:

```
public void ingresar(View view) {
    EditText num1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num1);
    EditText num2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num2);
    TextView total = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvresultado);
    if (num1.length() <= 0 || num2.length() <=0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Introduce un valor", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
             .show();
        return;
    }
    int dbnum1 = Integer.parseInt(num1.getText().toString());
    int dbnum2 = Integer.parseInt(num2.getText().toString());
    total.setText(String.valueOf(dbnum1 + dbnum2));
}
```

Comment: Hi Ted Hopp can you give a example?

Comment: @jhon - I added some sample code. If you want to receive the number of items to enter and then ask for each one separately, you might consider using a `Dialog`. See the [documentation on Dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) (in particular, the section on [creating a custom layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout) for how you might prompt the user for each number in turn.